# Как выбрать из массива несколько максимальных значений?

Tags: php

Не могу написать алгоритм на пхп, чтобы из массива достать несколько ключей с максимальным значением. Мой неверный пример:

```
    $a = array('a' => 1,
                'b' => 2,
                'c' => 3,
                'd' => 4,
                'e' => 4,
                'f' => 3,
                'g' => 5,
                'h' => 5,
                'i' => 2,
                'j' => 1,
        );

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $b = array_keys($a, max($a));
                здесь, мне надо удалить из массива а ключ, чтобы не брать его снова.
    }
```

Есть еще одна загвоздка, мне надо получить кол-во ключей равное count, но в массиве может оказаться несколько одинаковых максимальных значений(т.к. в моем сулчае это будут даты).

Получается что если при каунт 3, я выбрал значения (4,4,3,2). Мне надо удалить 2. При (4,3,3,2) - рандомно одну тройку.

В общем достать из массива N-ое кол-во записей, с учетом одинаковых значений.

Comment: посмотрите array_count_values и sort - дальше просто. !!!  Уще array_keys() со вторым параметром

Comment: Загуглил про функцию usort. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не вижу в этой задаче применения usort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$a = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    'd' => 4,
    'e' => 4,
    'f' => 3,
    'g' => 5,
    'h' => 5,
    'i' => 2,
    'j' => 1,
];

$count = 3;                      // Сколько значений нужно выбрать

arsort($a);                      // Сортируем массив в обратном порядке
$a = array_unique($a);           // Убираем дубликаты
$a = array_slice($a, 0, $count); // Выбираем нужное количество элеиментов
```

Comment: Сделал так же, еще до вашего ответа, спасибо :)